# What's the name of this distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I have two random variables $X$ and $Y$, both distributed uniformly over the interval $(0, 1)$. Is there a name for the distribution of
$$Z = \frac{X}{Y}?$$

I think there is one, but I cannot remember and am unable to find it. Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

pdf of $Z$ is $$h(z)=\frac{1}{2}, 0<z<1$$ $$\frac{1}{2z^2}, z>1$$ $$0 ,z\leq 0$$

see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_distribution#Uniform_ratio_distribution